# Unaccepting answer due to serial voting

Tags: support, serial-voting

Today I noticed a reputation reduction due to serial upvoting. While browsing through the reputation tab, I noticed that at the same time, a [legitimate question I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447782/reduce-on-tuples/40447950#40447950) was unupvoted and the answer was unaccepted.

My initial reaction was to add a comment, asking the OP to clarify if he had a sudden "change of heart" and the answer now no longer suffices. But then I went into the users profile and saw that he was last active *2 days ago*.

I'm assuming these are related as they also happened at the exact same time (`2017-09-21 21:11:10Z`). My question is, even though the user might be connected to the serial upvoting, should a legitimate answer to a general question be unupvoted and unaccepted?

**Edit:**

A screenshot for reference:

[image: Vote reduction]

Comment: Serial upvoting reversals don't have anything to do with why your answer was unaccepted. That's at the sole discretion of the person who asked the question.

Comment: @CodyGray But shouldn't a person who unaccepted and unvoted be seen at least at the time of unaccepting? That doesn't sound reasonable.

Comment: @CodyGray Also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286040/unaccept-answers-when-votes-are-invalidated

Comment: @CodyGray: In addition to the previous valid point Yuval makes, the voter should not have been able to change their vote recently, since the post was last edited a year ago.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: you keep mistyping Cody's name, so he is not getting notified of your comments.

Comment: @PeterDuhino Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I was perhaps too oblique. I'll try again. I see no evidence that the asker was involved in your serial vote reversal, so the two events are distinct. I can't see actual vote details, but I suspect someone else had upvoted the answer, and then *their* serial upvotes were reversed. The unaccept by the author was a separate action.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok. I still find this weird for a couple of reasons: 1. The voting reversal and the unacceptance happened at exactly the same time. 2. I still don't understand how a user which wasn't active for the last two days can unaccept an answer if he hasn't logged in 3. The reversal happened at around 00:30 PM during a holiday in Israel (which both OP and I happened to reside). The combination of these facts seem very odd to me.

Comment: @CodyGray Additionally, if the unupvote isn't related to the OP, why am I seeing both a bulk reversal with -147, and *an additional* 10 points subtracted individually under the question? Why isn't it just a part of the larger subtraction?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov well that would prove that one unupvote was done by choice and not because of a reversal script; coincidence works on a different level on this site. But still, I find it a valid question that you're asking. It is arguably fair that upvoting is reversed, but acceptance seems a step too far. It is very likely the fact that you gave a good answer that triggered this person to go happy happy joy joy after all, only what came after the acceptance should be reversed.

Comment: @Gimby The unupvote and the unacceptance happened *at the same time*. Coincidence? Not sure, this answer is almost a year old, what are the chances? The mixture of these "coincidences" feel odd. Adding a snapshot for reference.

Comment: Well that paints a picture; one where I assume its all part of one and the same reversal process but the unacceptance bit is reported inconsistently. Might be a tiny bug in the script.

Comment: @Gimby My thinking is along these lines. Although CodyGray has mentioned OP isn't related to the reversal, so why would the answer be unaccepted?

Comment: @CodyGray Any chance you can help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't really know any more than I've already said. I can't answer your follow-up questions. You need someone who knows more about how all of this works, like a CM or maybe another moderator who cares more about the nuances of the reputation system.

Comment: @CodyGray Would it be possible to refer them to this question, or elaborate on how I can contact one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cody Gray is partially correct in that the *automated* system that checks for irregular voting does not ever touch accept votes. However, this reversal was not processed by the automated system, it was processed by a staff member.

When staff have to get involved and find evidence of irregular voting, we wipe *everything* between the users, which includes and is not limited to:

- All upvotes
- All accept votes
- All suggested edit approvals
- All bounties

We don't have tools to explicitly select certain ranges of votes that should be invalidated or which specific types of votes were involved, nor should we. That makes the whole process entirely too complicated. All that matters in this decision is that somewhere there were irregular voting activities between two users that were too complicated for the automated system. If we find any, then we wipe the entire slate clean for those two users.

While your case in particular may have had a legitimate accept vote, not all cases are like yours. There are plenty of voting rings out there that do just create bogus questions for each other to answer and garner the additional accept reputation, or even accept answers just because they're friends even though there are much better answers out there. As well, there is nothing preventing the user re-accepting your answer at a later time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Cody wrote in the comments to the question: *I see no evidence that the asker was involved in your serial vote reversal*. According to your answer, this means that there need be  an explicit relationship between the voting reversal and the unacceptance of the answer, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: The user *was* involved in the invalidation that took place. I didn't process this invalidation so I couldn't really say how involved.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all the help! Although I must admit this does intrigue me to find out more what is behind this reversal :)

Comment: What would be a possible way to contact a mod about this, or even the person who investigated this issue? I think I understand what happened here.

Comment: bogus questions should be deleted; legitimate questions shouldn't have their accepted answer flag removed.

Comment: @Cœur While I generally agree with that statement, how would you distinguish a bogus question from a real one? Not only that, it would require mods to manually go through each question to determine that.

Comment: Ah, I missed that there was a manual invalidation here. Lack of cross-referencing bites again.

Comment: such a deep invalidation of rep gains sounds similar to what happens at accounts merge. Wonder if this is a coincidence