# My Upvotes on Another's Posts Were Reversed (and Accepts on my Answers Rescinded) Without Notification

Tags: support, serial-voting, voting-correction

Is it possible, and under what circumstances, would a user's votes (on a second user's questions) and a user's accepted answers (accepted by that second user) be revoked/unaccepted as part of a manual serial voting correction?

And for which reason would a user not be notified of such an action?

I believe that I have had votes, that I gave in good faith and in line with the rules, rescinded as part of a manual voting correction - naturally I resent this and its connotation. I also believe answers provided and accepted in good faith and non-serially have been unaccepted as part of that same manual voting correction. I have not been notified of any action.

---

I am concerned about this because six of my answers (months old and answered over a couple months) on another user's otherwise positively received questions were unaccepted at the same moment their reputation slid by 30 (or six question upvotes) as part of a voting correction.

At the very same moment as this, my reputation was manually corrected due to *very* obvious serial upvoting of my answers by who turns out to be the asker of those six questions. The user has stated that they did not unaccept my answers - that user actually re-accepted them before I had any contact with them while seeking to figure out what happened.

I believe the -30 voting correction for this user were my six upvotes being nullified - I would have upvoted these questions (one I know was upvoted at the moment I posted an answer - something I often do on worthy questions - that vote appears in the reputation history of that user but not the post timeline) but apparently I have not upvoted it as I am still able to up vote it (all six for that matter).

Further, it seems extremely unlikely that a user would decide to on a whim unnacept six answers of mine, within the space of a minute, at precisely the same time their reputation is "corrected" by six question upvotes (and at the same moment my rep was corrected), only to replace the accepts before I woke up.

It certainly is possible that this is all coincidence, but I consider this implausible however possible.

*Given the question touches on serial voting, I wanted to be completely transparent and go over both how I came to this conclusion and all the background, context, and tangential information, but after a few rightfully placed jokes about the tome I had written I have reduced the question to the core issue while attempting to give the question more of a generic application. See this [revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/374386/revisions) for the long read if need to fall asleep or have further questions about the specifics of my case.*

Comment: `"old answers of mine (6) that were accepted were mass unaccepted (likely by mod action)"` That is impossible as far as what any mod ever said on posts. Nobody has any possibility to accept or unaccept answers except the author of a question, and possibly devs, but that would be the first time I ever hear on meta.so about something like that. It is almost certainly a coincidence, but I'd be ok with being proven wrong.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thanks for the feedback - but I find it very unlikely that the voting corrected would appear with the same timestamp as the unaccepts (see image, which the user disavows) - but I admit that could be a coincidence, or perhaps I aroused enough suspicion that staff took a look.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - the image is of the other users reputation, mine goes down by 630 at the same moment in my reputation timeline.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clarifying. Sorry I missed that amongst the er... lengthy text ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the length - given the subject involves serial voting I figured complete transparency was warranted - which adds a bit of um, extra text. I could have just asked about the removal of votes as in the short version - but I would feel as though I was hiding important context that would surely be relevant to any explanation. *Also, user doesn't disavow the image - they disavow the unaccepts - which are since replaced*

Comment: @HansPassant yeah... it's long and winding (who titles a section down the rabbit hole?), I did enjoy the punishment line. It might be better for me to edit this to: Is it possible that a user would have answers (their own) unaccepted and their votes (given to others) retracted as a part of a manual serial voting correction without notification. Though I would imagine the answer without any evidence of the action be a straight no, placing everything else as a coincidence of timing - which I think improbable, but certainly possible.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356983/5267751 "When staff have to get involved and find evidence of irregular voting, we wipe everything between the users"  ( @FélixGagnon-Grenier )

Comment: @user202729, thanks for that, that probably covers the main gist of the question and assuages my worries  a bit - just feeling left out as to why there is no notification about this given a natural inference upon discovery without a notification would be that my actions were considered somehow wrong.

Comment: @AndrewReid But you do get a "voting corrected"... doesn't that count as a notification?

Comment: @user202729, that just tells me someone else's actions were suspect - not that my votes on that users posts were rescinded (because that doesn't change my reputation if I voted up) or that perhaps my answers weren't considered to be judged fairly for historic accepts (voting corrected -440 doesn't explain much of why or what). Votes are contributions to the site, if you are going to remove them at least have the common decency tell me that you assumed they were fraudulent and decided to wipe them from the system.

Comment: @AndrewReid You can [contact] the staff. We (meta users \ SE staff) are not responsible for voting correction.

Comment: @user202729, I know, but I feel this has been informative nonetheless (for me at least), I will follow up properly with them at some point. I'm certainly grateful for the information you linked to, which at least lets me infer that I wasn't necessarily targeted by hand, merely by process (which might not feel great, but it clears worries that I was personally suspected of a  wrong somehow, which was the primary point that had been bothering me).

Comment: Thanks for that @user202729. Fascinating, meta is, as always :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you state, on September 16 and 17 you flagged moderators indicating that you had been targeted by serial voting. Moderators looked into this and found that someone had indeed been targeting you with votes, so a standard vote invalidation request was submitted to the community team.

In almost all cases like this, the default action is to invalidate all votes between the two parties. That will include accept votes, so the accept mark will remain behind but the reputation from that will be removed. This shows as an "unaccept" in the reputation history.

In fact, I'm not sure if the tools for invalidating votes are fine-grained enough to only invalidate votes going one way (aside from serial downvoting, which is directional). In pretty much every case, the reason we're doing this is to prevent vote coordination between users.

Maybe a little more targeted message could have been sent to employees about wanting to invalidate only in one direction, but you had requested the votes be invalidated and the moderator involved might not have realized there were votes from you to be explicitly preserved.

Comment: I see, though naturally I didn't know where the votes were from - so I wouldn't have been able to request anything specific (I certainly didn't expect a slightly older account, but perhaps I'm naive). In this case I understand the other user received a mod warning about targeting users, would the other party (in this case me) ever receive any notice about suspected shenanigans and that their votes had been retracted? I assumed I had been assumed to be breaking rules while acting in good faith - any notification would have been welcomed to give some context. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AndrewReid - If we had thought you were coordinating with this user, we would have sent a warning to you describing what had happened. I think in this case the moderators involved didn't realize there were votes going from you that would be impacted by this. This was an unintended side-effect, and usually we only send messages in the case of problematic behavior, so this is a rare situation. Sorry about the confusion, this doesn't happen too often.

Comment: I'm quite satisfied now - this is precisely the clarity I was going for, now I can aim for that 100 000 mark with out worry (before I retire anyways) and the prize it comes with - a 1986 Honda Civic right? Oh, and um, I'm assuming you read the loong earlier revision given the specific flag references - sorry about the length there.